# Button click to web-view in desired activity

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

I'm in progress on developing an android application and I'm looking for how to implement the following cases.

1. How to open a web view in second activity by clicking a button in the
   main activity?
2. And, How to navigate back to the main activity when the back button is 
   pressed.

   3. I have 12 buttons in the main activity each opens a web view in the second  activity. For example button 1 is for google.then by clicking button 1  one can view web view of  google in the second activity.Like this button 2 is for Face Book.Then by clicking button 2  one  can view web view of Face Book in the  second activity.How to Implement this scenario for 12 buttons in the main   activity.

Comment: use intent for second activity and in second activity, in onCreate method open webview

Comment: Is it work if we have multiple buttons in the main activity,and when each button is clicked it will open the respective site in webview in the second activity?

Comment: use Intent on that button on which you want click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code in your secondActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Add following code in onCreate() of your secondActivity.java

```
Webview webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

Take a button in your firstActivity.xml

```
<Button
        android:text="Open"
        android:id="@+id/btnOpen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Redirect to secondActivity

```
btnOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class));
                    finish();

            }
        });
```

Add this in your onBackPressed

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FirstActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: Great!!!!! It works well.thanks for your help.But how to handle if we have two buttons in first activity.How to identify each buttons clicks  in the second activity.Thanks  Expecting your valued reply.

Comment: Just take a `public static int buttonVal=0;` inside your first activity then 

in button one's click listener add `buttonVal=1` and in button two's click listener add `buttonVal=2` now you can get that value in second activity by calling `FirstActivity.buttonVal` now put if condition like

`if(MainActivity.buttonVal==1)
 //button 1 is clicked
else
 //button 2 is clicked`

Comment: Sir, Could you please share the code for third requirement?

Comment: Just add another buttton like other two and in it's click event initialize it with some value and get the value in secondActivity like same above code. Also keep in mind that if you don't handle the code properly and if somehow buttonVal got null in secondActivity, then you might crash your app.

Comment: Can you please share the code with three buttons?I am new to android.